# Tinymce ImageManager Wired Up To Windows Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, tinymce

I'm considering moving from a dedicated server hosting environment to Azure. I'm using the ASP.NET Membership provider and every member has their own folder that houses their images (avatar, etc.). I have the Tinymce ImageManager wired up so that a logged-in user will only see their folder when selecting/uploading an image.

Is there a way to wire up the Tinymce ImageManager to Azure's blob storage in a similar way?

Answer (score 1):

This thread on their site indicates that this is not yet supported:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=24776

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see this accomplished is for you to rewrite parts of the Image Manager that perform I/O operations on the HDD. Which is no a rocket-science to implement.

Another way to move to Azure is to move your site for [Windows Azure WebSites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/).

Comment: I found an article that outlines how to make a custom file browser. I think I'll take your advice and write up something custom.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser

Comment: you may also check the default implementation of the iBrowser plugin for hints.

Comment: Thanks, I will check iBrowser out.